# How to use ngIf in datatable p-column

Tags: primeng, primeng-datatable

I need to use ngIf in a p-column, but I don't how to get value of datatable.

On primefaces I have "var" option in p:dataTable

I need this:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="objectList" >
   <p-column *ngIf="object.property"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

Comment: hard to understand your problem, may be using [ng-template](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/templating) inside column can help you.

Comment: @TimeTraveler object.property it's a boolean, I need to show p-column only if object.property = true. can I use ng-template directly without p-coloumn?

Comment: No. But I don't think it is a good idea to have different number of columns for different rows. With ng template you can choose to display nothing inside a column using ngif=object.property